# Delays between a sprites position change

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Right now I have a `NSArray` with `x` amount of coordinates inside; I have a sprite that needs to go to each of the points to go along the selected path. I tried using a for loop, but that does it in such quick succession that it appears to just teleport to the final destination. I've tried a with selectors but I can't get those to work either. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: how do you update the sprite positions?

Comment: Thats what I'm working on right now. I would like the final result to just use sprite.position = [locationsArray objectAtPosition: step];

Comment: errr, that will have them jump from one position to the next, is that what you want? You probably want to issue a CCMoveTo to the next point, and when there are no more actions, run the next CCMoveTo.

Comment: Yes that is, the sprites are like pieces on a board. What I have now is:`for (int i = 0; i<pathLength; i++) {
        t = [path objectAtIndex:i];
        move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0 position:[self positionForTileCoord:t.position]];
        [piece runAction:move];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an NSTimer

```
@implementation whatever
{
int count;
NSTimer *myTimer;
CCSprite *mySprite;
NSArray *locationArray;
}
```

and then start the timer fromsomewhere...

```
 count=0
 //1.0 is one second, so change it to however long you want to wait between position changes
 myTimer =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(movealong) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then it calls this until it goes through all the object

```
-(void)movealong{

//assuming array is full of CGPoints...
//mySprite.position = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];
//try this then
CGPoint newPoint = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];
mySprite.position = ccp(newPoint.x,newPoint.y);
//I think maybe THIS is what you need to do to make it work... 
//if you want it to not jump directly there
//you can also use CCMoveTo 
/*//  under actionWithDuration: put the same amount of time or less of what you had
  //  under scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in your NSTimer
    CCFiniteTimeAction *newPos = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:[locationArray objectAtIndex:count]];
    [mySprite runAction:newPos];
*/
count++;
if(count >= locationArray.count){
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS call from that at this line `mySprite.position = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];`

Comment: what kind of objects are in your array?

Comment: from this error, it seems like maybe the array is empty,
or not an array of CGPoints,..

Comment: Its not empty but I have to do this: `CCSprite *p=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Tile:%g,%g",p.position.x,p.position.y);` to get the points

Comment: Because for some reason `sprite.position = [array objectAtPosition: x];` doesn't work.

Comment: `CCSprite *p=[array objectAtIndex:i]; `

this will not work unless you have an array of CCSprites, can I see part of your code where you define what you put in the array?

Comment: hmm,...see my edit above try loading it in a point first actually...
`CGPoint newPoint = [locationArray objectAtIndex:x];`
`p.position = ccp(newPoint.x,newPoint.y);`

Comment: either way if you had it working with a for loop, extracting the position and setting it will work exactly the same way.  Except I used count, instead of what maybe most people would use i for a for loop..

Comment: Well the array is the end result of an A* pathfinding algorithm so it'd be quite lengthy.

Comment: Ok, well did you test the code with the above change?
`CGPoint newPoint = [locationArray objectAtIndex:x]; `

`p.position = ccp(newPoint.x,newPoint.y);`

Comment: I'm getting `Initializing 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') with an expression of incompatible type 'id'`

Comment: hmm,...make sure not to put * after CGPoint
so you are saying it will let you set this before,
`CCSprite *p=[array objectAtIndex:i];`, but not this?
`CCSprite *p.position=[array objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: If so maybe it is returning a CCSprite, and not a CGPoint if that is the case than try,...  `CCSprite *newSprite = [locationArray objectAtIndex:x]; p.position = ccp(newSprite.position.x,newSprite.position.y);`

Comment: `CGPoint tile = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];
 CCSprite *t = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];CCSprite t = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count];` All of these but the first give errors.

Comment: Right thats what I did and I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS call

Comment: Ok, then I believe that means it is an array of CGPoints, and you need to try it using ccp and not setting it directly like this 
`CGPoint newPoint = [locationArray objectAtIndex:count]; p.position = ccp(newPoint.x,newPoint.y);`
if you do this and it doesnt work,.. I need more information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that will place your sprite to position that is at some index (for example, _i) in the positions array. And at the end of this method call it again with delay, using CCDelayTime and CCCallFunc actions in sequence. And do not forget to increment index. Smth like

```
// somewhere in code to start move
_i = 0;
[self setNewPosition];

// method that will set the next position
- (void) setNewPosition
{
    sprite.position = // get position at index _i from your array here
    _i++;

    BOOL needSetNextPosition = // check if _i is inside bounds of your positions array
    if( needSetNextPosition )
    {
        id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: delayBetweenUpdate];
        id callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setNewPosition)];
        id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: delay two: callback];
        [self runAction = sequence];
    }

}
```

This is just example, but I hope, you can adapt it for your needs.